# Firefox places.sqlite does not contain history

Tags: firefox, browser

I'm trying to get the browser history programmatically. Here's what I've done (in python, using sqlite3):

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('/home/quantka/.mozilla/firefox/35lwme56.profile0/places.sqlite')
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT url FROM moz_places")
history = cursor.fetchall()
```

This always returns the same 11 results that only include default mozilla sites like "http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/central/", even after I use the browser and go to other websites. I have verified that I am querying the correct profile (I think I checked all the profiles and all of them have the same 11 default sites).

Just for context, I am using the browser to go to websites through mozrepl, I don't think that should cause this problem, but maybe it is?

I have seen this same approach work on a different computer where I have only one profile and browsed using firefox's GUI.

Thoughts?

Comment: kinda obvious, but I'd try using the browser to manually make a few history entries, then rerun your script. It's entirely possible mozrepl isn't putting its history in the same (or any) place.

Comment: I'd have a hard time doing that since I'm sshing into this machine and I can't seem to get x forwarding to work. I have tried starting firefox from the command line (no mozrepl) on the machine with a url, and that url does not show up in the history.

Comment: is the size/modification time of `places.sqlite` changing as you use mozrepl? Is it possible the history is being stored in a different table besides `moz_places`? I'm not sure, kinda grasping at straws here...

Comment: Have you thought of using [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) with Python and seeing if that populates the history properly?

Comment: It looks like places.sqlite is not changing size. If I'm going to do something possibly involved like installing stuff, I may as well try harder to get x forwarding to work...

Comment: well, if you need help with that you can always ask a question :)

Comment: I thought it might have been a permissions issue, but chmod 777 on the places.sqlite file didn't fix it, could it be some other permissions issue?

Comment: Maybe you need `firefox --no-remote`. Or saving history is simply disabled, either directly or due to private browsing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try querying directly from sqlite? While in the correct user profile directory you can use the following command to pipe the history to a text file or omit the dashes and quotes to have it print to terminal.

```
sqlite3 places.sqlite "SELECT strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S', visit_date/1000000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'),url FROM moz_places, moz_historyvisits WHERE moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id ORDER BY visit_date;" | tee /user/home/FirefoxHistory.txt
```

[Reference](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/14062/get-your-firefox-history)